# Expresso Store - UPS and FedEx shipping methods and free shipping after X amount

Tags: expresso-store, ups-shipping

I have found that topic [Expresso Store - Add free shipping when an order's subtotal is over an certain amount?](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/182/expresso-store-add-free-shipping-when-an-orders-subtotal-is-over-an-certain-a) but it looks like is not relevant to current Expresso Store and UPS or FedEx shipping method add-ons.

Is there any way to deactivate or force to do not count shipping on both methods?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Store 2, you can create a discount with a minimum "Purchase Total", then enable the "Free Shipping" option:

[image]

Alternatively, you could create a hidden "Free Shipping" option, then use conditionals in the checkout to automatically submit the free shipping method when the order total is over a certain amount.

Comment: I will test that option. Also I have created shipping rule for Free Shipping (value 0) for Minimum Order Total for X amount and put it as first rule, but in that case client must to update shipping. Question is can I have set it as default so always will come as selected?

Comment: Yes, you can make a "Free Shipping" shipping method and have it selected by default. You could then use template conditionals to submit a hidden field for the free shipping method when the order is over a certain amount.